# IAP: How to define product IDs for massive virtual products?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an educational iOS app now. I want to sell virtual songs that can be used in my app. Apple limits the total number of IAP products defined in one developer account to 10000. The problem is that the number of my sellable virtual songs may exceed this limit and it is not convenient to manage so many IAP products either.
My product owner dislike the idea of introducing virtual currency as IAP products because he think it is hard for our users to understand it and it will not provide a good user experience.

Anyone has similar experience and could advise me the strategy of defining IAP products for massive virtual goods? Many thanks.

Comment: It seems that in-app virtual currency is the best way to go. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're either going to want to go with the in app currency you talked about, which I think is a great idea, but if your boss really doesn't like that you will have to build a backend that handles the storage and selling of the songs. This will be a lot more work than the solution you proposed yourself; I think selling "song tokens" isn't hard to understand for users at all and will save you a lot of effort. Good luck!